# How do I configure built in form Component in CQ 5?

Tags: javascript, aem, sling

I have dragged the predefined Form component in my page.

[image]

I want to configure this form component i.e. by default it's  points to itself, and data goes in BulkEditor.
I want my data to be submitted to my own servlet. So how do I make the action="/MyServlet"

I also want to include my .js validation on this page, I tried using this link
http://www.sfu.ca/itservices/cms/howto/advanced/style-a-page/customjavascript.html
 but I just don't have the option of adding .js in my page properties, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CQ5 forms are submited into actions. In order to submit your form into a custom action you need to create an action resource type:

-Create a sling:Folder with a prop sling:resourceType= foundation/components/form/action

Then you create a script or servlet for that resourceType that respond to POST methods and  the post selector. This can be a jsp post.Post.jsp or a serlvlet (method=POST, selectors=post, extension=html).

To create a custom validation, you create a clientvalidation.jsp file under that same resourceType.

After that, you can edit your form and select your action.

[Adobe documentation about it](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/developing-forms.html) is pretty straighforward

Comment: I was able to post my data to SlingServlet using custom ActionType. Now I want to try another way, I want to Send data via AJax call to serlvet, the serlvet will return some result based to which I will redirect to a page. So where do I add this .js file .ie the file that contains the AJAX call !! and how do I use JQuery in CQ, like everyone, I would prefer Jquery.Ajax call as its easy $.ajax();
PLEASE NOTE I'M USING PREDEFINED FORM COMPONENT SO I CAN'T DO STUFF LIKE <cq:include clientLibs> to add .js file right as I don't have source code of componenet(form template)